# Does my Keras multiple output NN not converge because i have not sufficient layers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, regression

I am trying to build a neural network to predict 3 output values out of 63 inputs. I have a dataset containing two numpy arrays with the shape of [8100, 63] and [8100, 3] but when I try to feed them to Keras the model does not converge and the mean squared error is in the area of 10^11.

The function i used to calculate the Data does not have any non-linear properties so i first thought that one or two layers should be enough. with three layers the MSE is still in the area of 10^10 and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The regression should return three absolute Values which can be bigger than 1 - this is the reason why I didn't use softmax layers.

I would be really grateful for any input or help!

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import *
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import plot_model



np.random.seed(7)

#Define Input
tf_features_64 = np.load("IN.npy")
tf_labels_64 = np.load("OUT.npy")
tf_features_32 = tf_features_64.astype(np.float32)
tf_labels_32 = tf_labels_64.astype(np.float32)

X = tf_features_32
Y = tf_labels_32


#create Layers
visible = Input(shape=(63,))
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(visible)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(70, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(30, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(3)(x)


Optimizer = optimizers.adam(lr=0.001)
model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs = output)
model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['mse']
              )
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=400, batch_size=300, shuffle=True)

print(model.summary)
```

Comment: can you share your data set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we are using neural networks for classification we should use `softmax` at last layer with `categorical_crossentropy` **loss**.

```
output = Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
          loss='categorical_crossentropy')
```

For regression we should use `linear` output with `mse` loss

```
output = Dense(3)(x)
model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
          loss='mse')
```

You are using `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function and `mse` as a metric

```
model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['mse']
              )
```

Change loss function to `mse`

```
model.compile(optimizer=Optimizer,
              loss='mse')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That already looks a lot better. Now my loss is around 10^-5. I now have the problem that metrics=['acc'] returns values around 0.55. Do you have an idea what could be the reason for that?